# How to kill Apache / PHP server running on local host port 8080?

Tags: php, bash, apache, unix, port

I am currently running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6.

This is what I get when I load localhost:8080 in my browser: 
[Apache / PHP server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TFnH.jpg)

I do not know how this server was started on this port because I have never used these technologies. I do mess around with web development every now and then, but I do not know what I was doing when the server started. I have looked into how to kill the process and so far the closest I have come to ending the server is killing my chrome browser. Some of the things I have tried to find the process running on port 8080:

```
ps aux | grep 8080
lsof -t -i @localhost:8080
netstat -l -p | grep 8080
lsof -nP -i | grep 8080
```

There were a few more ones that looked similar that I tried, but I cannot recall all of them. When using the lsof commands, I would usually have to put sudo in front of them for anything to show up. I would sometimes get nothing to come back and sometimes I would get something like this: [Terminal output from `lsof`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADto2.jpg) and [`ps aux` output where the Postgres processes are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q61b4.jpg).

When I got processes back that had a PID associated with them, I would try to kill them with `kill -9 <PID>`. Normally I would have to force this with sudo because it gave me a permission denied error (probably not the best practice). When I did this, nothing appeared to happen except other processes appeared when I searched after I killed the initial ones. I also tried to end the processes associated with Postgres from ps aux, but that did not work either. It just seems like whatever processes I am finding are not the correct ones. Does anyone have any suggestions to help me find and kill the process that is hosting the server?

Comment: What OS and version are you running?

Comment: macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6

Answer (score 0):

From the command line it would be:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop
```

To prevent it from starting at the next reboot:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Note that I have no idea what else uses apache on your system, so this might break things.

Comment: This is what I get back when I try the top command: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service`

Comment: If apache is installed as a service, that should do it. You might want to check for typos.  You can also try turning off web services in the Web Sharing settings.

Comment: Well that's the weird thing. I don't recall ever installing apache, so I have no idea why it is running. And are you referring to web services within my browser or apache?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
ps -e | grep httpd
```

This will show you apache httpd PIDs.
Another way is to install [`pstree`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) using [**brew**](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install pstree
```

[**pstree**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) will show running processes as a tree. Then You can find the **PPID** with the following command:

```
pstree | grep httpd
```

Then you can use `kill` to terminate the process. I tested both ways on *macOS High Sierra*.

Comment: This is probably the closest I have come to fixing it. I can see the detailed processes running both ways. The issue I am still running into is that when I kill the processes from 
`ps -e | grep httpd`
They just come back. I typed in all the PID's and killed all of them at once. Is that the correct way to do that?

Also when I use pstree to do that same thing, they don't come back, but the service is still running on port 8080. They did come back to pstree after I deleted all from both pstree and ps. Do you see any problem with what I am doing?

Comment: @Bert Try using `sudo`, and if that doesn't work try with `kill -9` or combine them. Also did you see what process caused apache to be enabled e.g. _mamp, xampp application_?

Comment: I have used sudo with both. sudo and kill combined will kill the processes, but they just come back. As far as what enabled apache, I have no idea. This is what pstree displays if that helps:

Comment: `68580 root /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/conf/httpd.conf

   |--- 68581 daemon /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/conf/httpd.conf

   |--- 68582 daemon /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: You must somehow enabled postgresql for some reason. Also from the output it seems to run with root privileges (_so you'll probably need to use sudo_). Try with `sudo launchctl stop com.edb.launchd.postgresql-your_version`. To find the version use tab.

Comment: After trying that command, nothing appears to happen. The server is still running. Also, I don't know if this is significant, but any part of the command would not autofill with tab (not even the version). I had to check version with `postgres --version`. Would uninstalling postgres fix anything? I don't care about using it anymore.

Comment: My mistake, tab didn't work cause it wasn't a path. Anyway try one more thing, since you have the pids for apache try using `kill -KILL` the pid. Also did you restart your mac? Also check the activity monitor to see if any process seems familiar that may enables apache.

Comment: `kill -KILL` still lets them restart with different pid's. I have tried restarting several times. Also, looking through activity monitor, I can not tell if anything is running the apache service.

Answer (score 0):

```
lsof -nP -i | grep "TCP.*:8080.*LISTEN"
```

Use `lsof` to find the process that is waiting for connections ("LISTEN"ing) on port 8080. Use the PID column from that output to kill the process.

Comment: When I run that command, I get: `httpd        94           root    4u  IPv6 0x53ad559dfbdef59d      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd       219         daemon    4u  IPv6 0x53ad559dfbdef59d      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd       220         daemon    4u  IPv6 0x53ad559dfbdef59d      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd       221         daemon    4u  IPv6 0x53ad559dfbdef59d      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
httpd       654         daemon    4u  IPv6 0x53ad559dfbdef59d      0t0    TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)` -- After Killing all of them, the apache service is still running.

Comment: Sounds like the "kill" method is in question then. Is it the same PID afterwards (= kill signal is being ignored or not delivered) or different (= something is restarting the process).

Comment: The kill is going through with the addition of the sudo command. The PID's are changing, so they are being restarted somehow.

Comment: sudo doesn't guarrantee that a signal is received. Obscure cases will still run after `sudo kill -9` which is why I asked. But that's not your problem. Your problem is something is restarting this. That's harder to diagnose, but I'd start by looking at what log files in /var/log/ change when you kill the process. I'd also consider trying to win the race condition to open the port to see what log messages that produces. `nc -l 8080` can start a server on port 8080 and block something else from listening there.

Comment: @Bert - Apache has one process that runs as root and some number of other processes (depends on load and configuration) that run as a lower priv user. If you want to stop apache, you would be much better off using the OS's normal method of controlling services than trying to stab them in the back and hope they don't rise again. If the root process still runs, the children will come back.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I understand that by not killing the root, the children will come back, but when I view the tree of processes using `pstree | grep httpd`, and kill the "root" process, all of them still come back. Is there are way you would go about killing the root other than `sudo kill -9 <PID>`?

Comment: @Bert That should do it, assuming you're killing the correct processes. However you really don't want to kill apache. What you wan to do is stop it and disable it using the normal OS commands. If you kill it, launchd will just respawn another one.

Comment: @TerryCarmen Oh okay, so I have a process in activity monitor that is named "launchd" with a PID of 1. If I kill that, do I stop apache? If not, is there another way to disable it?

Comment: Don't do that. It runs all the services on your system. Just turn it off. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119674/disable-apache-autostart

Comment: @TerryCarmen I tried that before when you posted the other comment below. Here is the output of my terminal: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp2vr30k63jrf4z/Screenshot%202018-09-10%2011.44.07.JPG?dl=0
I don't know if this is an issue, but I do recall every installing apache on this machine, but it could have came with postgres. I have had postgres in this machine for a while without any issues, and out of nowhere, this server popped up.

Comment: If apachectl can't find apache, your installation is broken and you'll need to resolve that issue before moving on.

Comment: @TerryCarmen it's fully possible to have apache running multiple disconnected configurations, but apachectl only looks for the standard one.

Comment: It's possible but not likely that the OP intended this. He apparently doesn't want apache at all.

Comment: His apache appares to be running with some sort of postgres config, so odds of it being not the standard config are high.