# How to fix apachetl not finding apache instance and stop the server?

Tags: php, bash, macos, apache, unix

I am currently running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6.

I am trying to stop an apache server from running on my localhost port 8080. This is what I get when I load localhost:8080 in my browser: [Apache / PHP server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K4yn.jpg). From research and the help of others in: 
[How to kill Apache / PHP server running on local host port 8080?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209105/how-to-kill-apache-php-server-running-on-local-host-port-8080) I believe that my apache installation is broken because when I run the command `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop`, it says: [cannot find specified service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H8Bq.jpg).

I do not ever recall installing apache or starting the server, but it could have something to do with postgres. Is there a way I can try to fix my installation so that I can find the apache instance and stop it when I run `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop`? If it is not an installation error, I am open to hear other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EnterpriseDB logo on the screenshot kind of hints that this is not a standard installation of Apache, but something bundled together with EnterpriseDB, and it seems to have its own control scripts.

If you are not using it and do not plan to use it in the future, the most sensible thing would be to [uninstall it completely](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/10.0/instguide/PostgreSQL_Installation_Guide.1.21.html).

If you just want to stop it, try running `sudo /Library/PostgreSQL/EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP/apache/bin/apachectl stop`

But if you only stop it, most probably it will start again automatically after next reboot, so if you're not uninstalling it, you can at least disable it. [Here's a post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/244589/prevent-postgresql-from-running-at-startup) (which is where you should've asked this question instead of SO, btw) where it was discussed how to disable the PostgreSQL server.

AFAIK, Apache is started as a part of the whole thing, so it should get disabled together with it.
The post is a bit older but the steps should be very similar, if not the same (apart from the PostgreSQL version).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)